# How to Query repos Information using Azure CLI in powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to run a pipeline with that will collect information about

1. List of repos
2. Branches of each repo
3. Latest Commit
4. Author of the commit

I've gone through the docs[az repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-list) but I'm unable to execute it because I'm trying to do it via [SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)
Thanks in advance...